# How to repair Grub if yannubuntu doesn't exist?

Tags: boot, grub2, xubuntu, grubrescue, boot-repair

I am using Xubuntu live USB because I need to repair Grub (I am in mode grub rescue) but when I try to install boot repair it says this to me, with Wi-Fi online, of course:

```
xubuntu@xubuntu:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~yannubuntu/ubuntu/boot-repair'.
ERROR: '~yannubuntu' user or team does not exist.
```

How to install this application if the user doesnt exist anymore? Or are there other applications or other ways, for example in terminal, to repair or to fix the broken Grub? Thank you in advance.

Comment: sorry if this is obvious - this is the error you'll get when you aren't connected to the internet, e.g. no wifi connection

Answer (score 4):

In my case i forgot to connect to the internet. After connecting to the wifi it worked.

Answer (score 1):

The use definitely exists, I don't know what is the cause of problem, however here is an alternative solution to install this application:

Go to the PPA page: [here](https://launchpad.net/~yannubuntu/+archive/ubuntu/boot-repair).

Click on "Technical details about this PPA", then from "Display sources.list entries for:" select your Xubuntu version, for example `zesty`, `xenial`, etc. if you don't know the code name run:

```
$ lsb_release -sc
xenial
```

After selecting your Xubuntu version, it will outputs something look like this:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu zesty main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu zesty main
```

Open this file: `/etc/apt/sources.list` using an editor with root access.
For example in terminal using `nano`:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

or from GUI using `mousepad`:

```
gksudo mousedpad /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Add those links to this file and save it. Now to add the PPA's signing keys:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 1024R/60D8DA0B
```

After all run an `update`:

```
sudo apt update.
```

then install boot repair.

Comment: after trying to add the signing key, i get an error GPG saying it's ``not a key ID: skipping``. this also happens with the much longer key on LaunchPad.